# Different number of bytes when storing images to Android Q vs previous versions

Tags: java, android, mediastore

we have a situation that we don't entirely understand.  In our app, the user selects images, which are saved to disc and mapped to their pictures folder.  Then when the user is ready to upload the selected images, we use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to turn them each into a byte array, which is then turned into a string of Hex characters.  So far this has worked well, even in areas with low-quality data coverage.

Our process for saving the image to disc (cut down for clarity and generally found here in Stack Overflow) is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            imageDir = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "temp", null);
            bytes.close();
```

Since `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` has been deprecated, we have started looking at code for Android Q and above:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "location_image.jpg");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            Uri uri = inContext.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            OutputStream imageOutStream = inContext.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

            imageDir = String.valueOf( uri );
            Boolean b = inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, imageOutStream);

            imageOutStream.close();
```

However, when we use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to upload images stored with this new process for Q and above, the array is 3-4 as large, which in turn is messing up our data upload process.  For example, an image that is stored as 1080x1080 in the old process (<Q) typically has a byte array of around length 380k, while with the new process (>=Q) it swells to 1.4M.

Why is this??

We can reduce JPEG quality in the new process to 80-90%, and will get the same length byte array as the old process.

Comment: Having just your description my guess would be that previous Android version capped the quality parameter to ~80-90 whereas newer ones actually really use 100 when you pass 100. A normal 1080x1080 photograph at 100 quality in JPEG should be on the order of at least 1.4M, that seems reasonable. If you got 380k before, then that's a hint that 100 wasn't really used.

Comment: The `insertImage()` method saves images at 50%: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.1.0_r27/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#989. It's always been like that, AFAIK.

Comment: @MikeM.: that make a slot of sense. It indicates that the 100 in the original code was irrelevant (in fact the entire `compress` call is pointless in that case) and if OP desires the same quality in newer releases, they should use a quality value of 50 as well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, thanks for the info.  @Mike M., just for curiosity's sake, what happens in the previous compress line if you select less than 100%?  Is it overridden somehow by insertImage, added, multiplied?  In theory could we just remove `inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);` ?

Comment: @user3398945: as far as I understand `compress` doesn't affect `inImage` itself at all. All it does is write a compressed JPEG version to `bytes` (which you then seem to not do anything with). So in the code above it seems entirely pointless and should be removed without replacement.

Comment: If the user selects an image then you will get an uri to a file. A file. If you wanna make a copy of that file you should not use an intermediate bitmap. If you want to upload an image file you should not make an intermediate bitmap first. So there is nothing to compress. Never. Unless you wanna resize or do image editing.

Comment: `Our process for saving the image to disc` Well that code saves a bitmap to disk. But where is this bitmap coming from? From a user selected file? Why making a copy?

Comment: @blackapps, the user crops the image, and we also set it to a standard dot size, thus the need to create a new image file.  But obviously we weren't entirely clear on how that process functions.

Comment: Ok. But once you created a resized file there is no need to use an intermediate bitmap to upload that resized file. And i would also not hex encode a file at upload as then you have to transfer twice as much bytes.

Comment: @blackapps, yeah we don't create an intermediate bitmap.  The code I pasted here was just for saving the cropped image, as upload is in a different part of the app.  Thanks for the hex comment- we'll definitely work on that angle.  I am sure you've noticed that we've taken boilerplate in a couple of places and once it worked, we didn't really think too much more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @Mike M in above comments.

`insertImage` always sets quality to 50%, newer code just had to match:

```
Boolean b = inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, imageOutStream);
```

Also best in older (deprecated) code to remove:

```
inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
```

as it had no real function.

And in both cases, certain models running Android 10 can have a problem with non-unique image titles.  So it helped to change them to:

```
"image_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg"
```